# How can we provide a stable reference voltage to a voltage regulator if we don't have a stable source to begin with?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, voltage-divider

In voltage regulator circuits i always see a "reference voltage", that is supposed to be used to tune the regulator to the voltage we want to regulate the output to.

But since we don't have a regulated source to begin with, how can we provide that stable "reference voltage" ?

Comment: Isn't that what filters are for?

Comment: Use a Zener to get a fixed reference voltage and feed it to the circuit. Even if source voltage changes (and is above breakdown boltage), the zener will provide the reference.

Comment: Google "Bandgap voltage reference"

Comment: Because analog circuit genius Bob Widlar figured out how to implement a temperature compensated bandgap voltage reference in integrated circuits back in 1971.

Comment: There's dozens of ways to build references, from icewater/boiling water and thermocouples, to speed-regulated generators, to atomic batteries.

Comment: The short answer is *negative feedback*.

Comment: Nearly every voltage reference device uses some form of negative feedback. In some cases, this can be entirely electrical, but the best references are also include temperature compensation, which is itself another form of negative feedback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The primary reference is something like a [zener diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_diode) or a [band-gap reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandgap_voltage_reference) or maybe a [floating gate MOSFET](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4526193/). The regulator is something like a power amplifier that provides an output that is proportional to that voltage. The gain of that amplifier determines how much the output voltage changes with load current changes (load regulation).

Although the reference can operate okay from unregulated input, there will be some change with input voltage (line regulation). To improve that regulation we can start up the reference in some way and run it mostly from a voltage or current related to the output voltage. This is called "bootstrapping".

Here is the block diagram of an [MC78M05](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MC78M05-D.pdf) showing the basic regulator and protection circuitry.

[image]

[Here](http://www.righto.com/2014/09/reverse-engineering-counterfeit-7805.html) is how the schematic of an LM7805 breaks down:

[image]

The green part is the startup circuitry. The yellow is the bandgap reference. The rest is the error amplifier, feedback divider and protection circuitry.

Answer (score 2):

There are all kinds of voltage references available depending on your needs and price range.  Zener diodes are drifty with temperature but cost pennies, while LTZ1000s are amazingly stable but cost in the $40-50 range.

In between there are a wide variety of references in many voltages, packages, and quality levels.  [image].